# Area of the Butterfly Curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, area

Need help with this question:

> Find the area of the butterfly region
>   $\int\int 
> 1 dA $,
>   where $R$ is given in polar coordinates
>   as$ 0 ≤ r ≤ r(θ)$ where $r(θ)$ is defined
>   as
>   $r(θ) = 8−sin(θ) + 2 sin(3θ) + 2 sin(5θ)−sin(7θ) + 3 cos(2θ)−2 cos(4θ)$

So I calculated the two integrals using the following bounds: $\int_0^{2π}$$\int_0^{r(θ)}  rdrd(θ).$ However, this doesn't necessarily work because you get a value of 0 after solving. Thus, should I have taken the first quadrant and multiplied by 4? PLEASE help!!!!!!

Comment: Since you're interested in the area, you should try taking the absolute value of your integrand.

Comment: That still gives me 0. You can solve it in terms of r first, which gives you 1/3r((theta))^3.

Comment: Hint: use $A=\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(\theta)d\theta$.

Comment: @xpaul the point still remains: 2pi and 0 are equivalent. This still gives me an area of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Noting 
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2m\pi)\sin(n\pi)dx=0, \text{ if }m\neq n, \int_0^{2\pi}\sin(2m\pi)\cos(n\pi)dx=0, \int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(n\pi)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(n\pi)dx=\pi, $$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
A&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}r^2(θ)d\theta\\
&=&\frac12\int_0^{2\pi}(8−\sin(θ) + 2 \sin(3θ) + 2 \sin(5θ)−\sin(7θ) + 3 \cos(2θ)−2 \cos(4θ))^2d\theta\\
&=&\frac12(128\pi+\pi+4\pi+4\pi+\pi+9\pi+4\pi)\\
&=&\frac{151}{2}.
\end{eqnarray}